Owl Carousel 2 Swipe One Tile At A Time
When building a carousel with Owl Carousel I can swipe  on a touch device more than one tile at a time. It appears to be the default setting. What would I need to do to prevent more than 1 tile either way from sliding.
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/center.html
